# Very small scale electronic goods manufacturing regulations

Tags: safety, emc

I would like to make a 12v rechargeable battery operated robotic toy, for sale as a kit. This would be more of a hobby for me, selling say 5 units a month with a very small turnover. It would just involve a standard wall socket charger, a few 12v motors / servos, a microprocessor, a couple of li-ion batteries and an enclosure. I would probably have the pcb made professionally. I would offer the option to have it unsoldered or solder it myself, and I would make the enclosure pieces myself.

As far as the electronics and electrical circuity goes, what regulations, if any, would I have to be concerned about? It would not use any kind of radio link, and other than the motors, would not involve any kind of electrical circuits prone to EMI emission. I want to avoid buying any EMI detection tools given the expected tiny turnover. I am interested mainly in UK regulations, but any country's regulations would be helpful to give me an idea of what to expect.

(PS, any regulations regarding mechanical safety would be a bonus but not expected here!)

Thanks

Comment: Since you're in the UK, you may want to search blog posts on the [RaspberryPi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/) site. They too wanted to sell their product labeled as a "kit"  and avoid the need for testing by regulatory agencies, but due to number of manufactured units couldn't. If I remember correctly, they explained how the regulations work in that post, which I can't find at the moment.

Comment: The Rasberry pi articles @AndrejKo mentions are possibly   [Compliance testing](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/852) ,  [An update on CE compliance](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/878) and [Testing’s done!](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/978)

Answer (score 2):

The key to safety for electronic goods is to use a cUL/CE approved external adapter, then the AC product directives do not apply to the toy as it is low voltage DC.

The EC (european commission) for EMC have released a new proposal as a legislation directive. [11/2011](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=COM:2011:0765%3aFIN%3aen%3aPDF) to harmonize all members of the EU.
It complies with  business "proportionality" so as not to impose the same burden on smaller corporations. This framework adds to existing new framework (2008) that applied to accreditation, market surveillance and marketing.

The new framework is being proposed to raise consumer confidence in certified products so it must be legislated and be enforced.

It still retains "The conformity assessment obligation should require the manufacturer to perform an electromagnetic compatibility assessment of apparatus, based on relevant phenomena, in order to determine whether or not it meets the protection requirements under this Directive. ".
So that means someone who is qualified to assess your product's EMC must document   what tests were done to do this. This means Egress /Ingress radiated, conducted and ESD. How you conduct this does not mean you have to go to a certified agency to test it, but to test whether that is necessary.

They go on to say "identifying the electromagnetic compatibility characteristics of these installations should be sufficient to ensure exemption from the conformity assessment procedure."

As I see it, any business that is responsible will conduct the necessary tests to see if it further tests are required. This proposed framework for legislation will give the EC more teeth.

i.e. By comparing a reliable competitor product who is certified with your own, might be suitable to document relative performance to assess exemption from conformity at a certified lab. But that takes an expert to decide.